# Redireccionar con href y moverme a section html

Tags: html, jquery, script, href, enlace

Hola quisiera saber si es posible redireccionar a un aspx y moverse a un section 
 de este mismo pero a la misma vez por medio de href="#..." actualmente tengo dos paginas .aspx con un menu, pero al irme a la segunda y querer regresar, esta solo me redirecciona al primer .aspx y lo hago con el href="" de esta forma y con este script:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="Redirect();">Pagina 2</a></li>

    <script>
       function Redirect()
       { location.href = "Inicio.aspx"; }
    </script>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero adicional a ello quisiera que después del direccionamiento cumpla la función "saltarA" como se muestra en el ejemplo:

```js
function saltarA(id, tiempo) {
  var tiempo = tiempo || 1000;
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, tiempo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:saltarA('#seccion')">Pagina 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Redirect();">Pagina 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p><strong>Pagina 1</strong></p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<section id="seccion">
<p><strong>Despues de ser redireccionado, quisiera que se transporte hasta este punto de mi pagina 1</strong></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas redireccionar a otro aspx y que el scroll se coloque en cierta posición solo agrega al final del link el símbolo # seguido del id del elemento que está en la posición deseada.

```
location.href="Inicio.aspx#seccion":
```

Considerando tu comentario, si prefieres que el movimiento sea animado, puedes enviar el id como parámetro:

```
location.href="Inicio.aspx?id=seccion":
```

Y después en el evento `ready` leer ese parámetro y llamar a tu función `saltarA`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var id = getUrlParameter('id'); //Ver link para obtener ésta función
       saltarA("#"+id, 500);
});
```

Link para ver función que obtiene parámetros de URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js

---

En Inicio.aspx el script quedaría:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var id = getUrlParameter('id'); 
     saltarA("#" + id, 500);
});

function saltarA(id, tiempo) {
     var tiempo = tiempo || 1000;
     var section = $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, tiempo);
}
```

Y en los otros aspx:

```
function Redirect() {
     location.href = "Inicio.aspx?id=about";
}
```

Comment: AarónBC., si, tienes razón, el detalle está en que este método hace que se posicione de una forma muy rápida, es por ello que quiero adicionarle la función que menciono en mi consulta, gracias :D

Comment: Edité la respuesta para agregar una posible solución, saludos :)

Comment: No redirecciona lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma llamandolo desde el li:                         <li><a href="#" onclick="Redirect();">Inicio</a></li> 
    <script>

        function Redirect() {
            location.href = "Inicio.aspx?id=about";

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var id = getUrlParameter('id'); //Ver link para obtener ésta función
                saltarA("#" + id, 500);
            });
        }

Comment: Solo para confirmar, ¿el código en de la función Redirect si se está ejecutando? ¿La variable id si toma el valor "about"?

Comment: lo  hice asi pero solo redirecciona: <li><a href="#" onclick="Redirect();">Nosotros</a></li>

 <script>

        function Redirect() {
            location.href = "Inicio.aspx?id=about";
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var id = getUrlParameter('id'); //Ver link para obtener ésta función
                saltarA("#" + id, 500);
            });
        }

        function saltarA(id, tiempo) {
            var tiempo = tiempo || 1000;
            var section = $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, tiempo);
        }

    </script>

Comment: El código `$(document).ready...` debe ser llamado fuera de la function Redirect()... Puedes ver el ejemplo en la respuesta editada